# What does it mean to "put as much arm as she could into hers"?

Tags: phrases, american-english

What does "put as much arm as she could into hers" mean?

[image: put as much arm as she could into hers]

Comment: It means put as much force (which comes from/through the muscles of the arm) into the spin.

Comment: Posting images of text is deplored. You should supply text that can be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

It's an expression that means put as much *effort* as you can into something.

In the context of the passage, the woman wants to put as much *arm strength* into the *spin of the wheel* as she can. There is no actual wheel; it's a metaphor.

---

The meaning of the passage can be seen by paraphrasing it as follows:

> Jeannette wanted to put as much effort into preparing for her parole hearing as she was capable of.